# typeahead provider error on upgrading ui bootstrap to 0.13 from 0.12

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have recently upgraded to ui bootstrap 0.13 to make use of the popover template feature .But i am getting the following error.

> Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- tooltipTemplateTranscludeDirective
>
> Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- typeaheadMatchDirective

I was using typeahead of ui.bootstrap.typeahead 0.12 before. I am on AngularJS v1.2.26.Is this an compatibility issue? if yes is there any workaround other than upgrading angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have angular js 1.3 version to resolve this issue. At present even I am facing the same issue and looking for work around.

Read this blog :
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3832